# Minecraft survival House

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a house and there is a cave just some blocks near it and it is underground. I hear monsters and I am not being able to sleep in my bed. I have  completed half of building my house. Is there anything I can do that I'm able to sleep again?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me multiple times; here are some ways you can fix it:

1. **Place torches in the cave.** By placing light sources, you can prevent monsters from spawning in that area. *Bonus: you can find valuable resources.*
2. **Place slabs on the cave floor.** This isn’t recommended, as it would take a lot of resources, but technically, it’s a feasible option that some people do.
3. **Move your house.** This is another way to prevent cave issues. It’s pretty self explanatory.

Those are the only ways I could think of stopping and the cave issues you stated.

Comment: Of course there are also [more radical](https://youtu.be/FYc6IcVx0C8?t=111) ways of spawnproofing the terrain...

Comment: @SF. Yes, many options.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot sleep is because there are mobs nearby, you must kill the mobs in the radius around you to sleep, you can also light up the cave to stop this from happening again.